# ¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar el diseño del grid de un bootstrapTable?

Tags: javascript

Iré al grano, tengo un grid hecho con bootstrap-table.js (v1.15).
El diseño es un poco simple a decir verdad y luce masomenos así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero pasar a algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay una forma de hacerlo con el mismo bootstrap table o me sugieren alguna otra libería Js para hacer un grid de ese estilo?
Acepto sugerencias y de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Si sabes CSS y HTML eso lo puedes hacer en un momento basándote en las tags de Bootstrap

Comment: algun ejemplo? ya que todo lo que conforma el grid se hace a través de configuración por JS y en la plantilla html solo tengo la etiqueta table con su id al cual hago referencia en una scope de esta manera $scope.grid = $('#grid').bootstrapTable({...

Comment: Te basas en el [table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) de boostrap y usas css para darle formato. Luego el js para que te replique las celdas y en un momento lo tienes hecho

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/tagged/users) te dejo algunos ejemplos con su código para que lo puedas ver